# Java Swing JFrame disable mouse hovering for an overlay

Tags: java, swing, jframe, overlay, mouse

I am trying to make an overlay for csgo using swing(JFrame)
I've accomplished everything I need for it but there is 1 small bug I can't fix. I've looked everywhere on how to fix it and I can't figure it out!

Whenever I hover my mouse over anything that is being rendered it will give my mouse "focus" and tab me out of the game!

```
package com.rigadrinksbleach.csgo.external.overlay;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.rigadrinksbleach.csgo.external.Start;
import com.rigadrinksbleach.csgo.external.hack.Hack;

public class ExternalOverlay extends JFrame {

public ExternalOverlay() {
    super("Overlay");
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void loop() {
    this.repaint();
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    for(Hack hack : Start.getHacks().getHacks()) {
        hack.draw2d(g);
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    //g.drawRect(0, 0, this.getBounds().width - 1 - this.getBounds().x, this.getBounds().height - 1 - this.getBounds().y); //debug border
    this.draw(g);
}

}
```

[image: Gif of the problem] 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to use `frame.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: That didn't work :/

Comment: Good day, has a solution been found? I faced the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I know a fix for this.
Just change `setVisible` to False.